# ASP.NET - How can I check if an array is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How can i check if array is null, if is not null display

```
@foreach (var Phones in compInfo.Phones)
{
    if (Phones == null)
    {
        @Phones.CellNumber
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `@if (compInfo.Phones != null) { }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the phone list equals null before going to loop through it like this.
May i also suggest that you are trying to show the cell number of the phone is not null but that wouldn't be the case if its looping through all the values so it couldn't be null

i corrected below

```
@if (compInfo.Phones != null){ 
    foreach (var phone in compInfo.Phones)
    {
        if (phone.CellNumber != null)
        {
            @phone.CellNumber
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```html
@if(compInfo != null)
{
   @foreach (var Phones in compInfo.Phones)
     {
       if (Phones == null)
          {
           @Phones.CellNumber
          }
     }
}
```